# P(X=$\frac{1}{2})$ in $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$

Tags: probability

Sounds reasonable to think that the probability is 0, but sigma-additivity doesn't allow that. Does this have to do with having to choose an explicit definition of "random" choosing?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. There is indeed no uniform probability on $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$ if that's what you mean.

Comment: You can't make sense of your question, if you can't tell us what $X$ stands for. I mean, I gather it's supposed to be a random variable, but which random variable?

Comment: @drhab and Gerry, thank you both. I am still learning and trying to understand what it means to be random and what uniform probability means.

Comment: There are any number of textbooks that will explain these things to you. Also, you can't ping two people in one comment.

Comment: Making any progress, AAN?

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you. I am taking a course in Probability Theory in the university, so I'm studying this material now.